# How to set SelectList.DataValueField to whole object of List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created 2 Html.DropDownList with Razor.

```
 <p>Category:</p>
        @Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList(catList, "Id", "category"), "Select category");
        <p>SubCategory:</p> 
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SubCategory, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Id", "Subcategory"), "Select sub category",new {id="subCategory" });
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SubCategory);
```

Model for second DropDownListFor looks like this.

```
namespace OnlineShop.Models

{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    public partial class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter name of product")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter article of product")]
        public string Article { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter description of product")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter price of product")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select picture of product")]
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter date of product")]
        public System.DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose subcategory of product")]
        public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }//property that i want to associate with SelectList.DataValueField.
    }
}
```

then i created JSon result method.

```
  public JsonResult GetSubs(int category)
    {
        List<SubCategory> subs = goods.SubCategorySet.Where(x=>x.Category.Id==category).ToList();
        return Json(new SelectList(subs, "Id", "Subcategory")); //here is row of code that i want to change.
    }
```

how to set `SelectList.DataValueField` as  `SubCategory`,instead of `Id`?

Comment: your question is unclear. What do you mean make the value field of the selectlist to be SubCategory?  The SelectList is already generated by `subs` which is a list of type SubCategory? what would you set the textfield as?

Comment: The data value field in a SelectList should correspond to the value of the text field. so if your data field was SubCategory, then what text value would that correspond to?

Comment: I want to paste something like this new SelectList(subs, "SubCategory", "Subcategory").Becouse all options in dropdownlist,sends just Id to the controller,when i submit form,instead of  SubCategory object to controller.That's why in controller i get null in Product.SubCategory instead of value.

Comment: Your 2nd dropdownlist makes no sense. You cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object (in your case `SubCategory`) - you need to bind it to a simple property, e.g. `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SubCategory.ID, new SelectList(...` And you keep the `SelectList` constructor as it is. Suggest you also refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for how to implement cascading dropdownlists

Comment: Thank's for answer,i new in asp.net mvc and i thought that it is possible to use complex object as value for SelectListItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you cannot load the subcategory class in the drop down. But what you can do is save the ID from the dropdown and use that ID to retrieve the appropriate item from the database and then add it to your entity.

You can create a parameter in your action's parameter list with the same name and type as the dropdown to retrieve the value.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SubCategoryID", ViewBag.Subs, "Select an Option", new { @class = "pretty" })

[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(Product model, int SubCategoryID)
{

  //here you can retrieve your item from the database using the value in
  //SubCategoryID
  //Psuedo code below:

  Subcategory test = goods.SubCategorySet.Where(sc => sc.id == SubCategoryID);

  model.SubCategory = test;

  //save/update model here
}
```

As you create a new product subcategory will be null upon post back but that's when you use the ID to assign the selected subcategory.

you will also use the id to show currently selected subcategory if you are on an edit screen for your entity.  just get the id and use it in the selected value property of your select list.

```
new SelectList(subs, "Id", "Subcategory", SubCategoryID));
```

Comment: Yes but as for as i know, value can be any property or field of class,but not whole class.I need to make it for whole class in subs collection.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misunderstood you.  I wouldn't advise loading whole class instances in the dropdown anyway simply because of load times for the amount of extra HTML you'd be loading.  I will edit the answer with the proper solution.

Comment: Ok i got it,the best way is to store value in id,and than by id find some subcategory in collection in controller right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I know this doesn't exactly answer your question but please mark it as right if It solves your problem. Or, let me know if you need anything else.